# RSS Feed stopped working periodically

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, rss

Our client has 3 environments: QA, UAT and PROD.

On all of them we have different RSS Feed Viewer Web Parts.

All feeds that points to the internal sites are working without any issues.

There is 1 feed that is bringing the feed from the external resource. They have started to have problems with this feed recently on PROD. After investigation I have found that it happens only on one WFE. So, we disable this server from the load balancer and after some time the same issue started to happen on another WFE.

So, we have enabled the first server again and did Recycle of the application pool. After that it started to work again. However, it was only temporarily. After some time it stopped working again.

Any idea what might be the issue.

Btw, once the problem starts in ULS Log we have exceptions related to Authentication.

Here is the exception

> 10/30/2014 12:14:27.64    w3wp.exe (0x1128)   0x1698  SharePoint Portal
>   Server    Web Parts   8imh    High    RssWebPart: Exception handed to
>   HandleRuntimeException.HandleException System.Net.WebException: The
>   underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a
>   send. ---> System.IO.IOException: Authentication failed because the
>   remote party has closed the transport stream.     at
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReadFrame(Byte[] buffer, Int32
>   readBytes, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)     at
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer,
>   AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)     at
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.ForceAuthentication(Boolean receiveFirst,
>   Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)     at
>   System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult
>   lazyResult)     at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.runTryCode(Object
>   userData)     at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.ExecuteCodeWithGuaranteedCleanup(TryCode
>   code, CleanupCode backoutCode, Object userData)     at
>   System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
>   executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)     at
>   System.Net.TlsStream.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult result)
>   at System.Net.TlsStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
>   at System.Net.PooledStream.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32
>   size)     at System.Net.ConnectStream.WriteHeaders(Boolean async)
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.BaseXmlDataSource.GetXmlDocument()
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SingleDataSource.GetXPathNavigatorInternal()
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls.SingleDataSource.GetXPathNavigator() 
>   at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.DataFormWebPart.GetXPathNavigator(String
>   viewPath)     at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.DataFormWebPart.PrepareAndPerformTransform(Boolean
>   bDeferExecuteTransform)   c5682911-db42-4a5c-a072-8f0bb63a31ae

Comment: could you please share the error detials

Comment: Does server have direct connection to external feed or do you use proxy?

Comment: do you have the proper proxy settings in the config file? <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="false">
    <proxy usesystemdefault="true" proxyaddress="<proxy address>" bypassonlocal="true" />
</defaultProxy>

Comment: I have <defaultProxy/>. When I tried this way Site stopped working at all. I decided not to play with it anymore until I have to. It is PROD. I cannot full around there.

Comment: Palo, 
I think it is, otherwise why would it work after recycling?